# Why isn't my Android not charging at night?

Tags: battery

I have a Motorola Turbo 2. It's not charging properly at night. Yesterday I woke up and the battery was at 1% even though I had it looked up to the charging cable. Last night my phone was fully charged, yet this morning it was down to 45%. I kept it looked to the charging cable.

How do I find out if my Android's battery is defective or the problem is with the cable?

Is over charging a phone's battery damaging to the phone?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried a different cable and/or charger? If it still occurs then it suggests an issue with the battery. If it doesn't it is an issue with the cable and/or charger.

Comment: Take the battery out and leave it out for 30 seconds. Then put it back in.

Comment: Why isn't my android not Charging at night? That's a double negative. I think you meant why isn't my android Charging

Comment: I might be overcharging it. Of course, it might be my charger itself. I know I have overcharged it. As for taking my battery out of the phone, I don't believe I can.